# show class order by id

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have few div with same class but different ids

```
<div class='box' id='zz1'></div>
<div class='box' id='zz2'></div>
<div class='box' id='zz3'></div>
<div class='box' id='zz4'></div>
<div class='box' id='zz5'></div>
```

All div are display:none only first div is visible. What i want is if i click on on #zz1 then it will be hide and #zz2 will visible and if i click on #zz2 the it will hide and show #zz3.. I can use condition here  like this

```
$('.box').click(function(){
$(this).hide();
var getId = $(this).attr('id'); 
if(getId == "zz1") {  $("#zz2").fadeIn(); }
if(getId == "zz2") {  $("#zz3").fadeIn(); }
if(getId == "zz3") {  $("#zz4").fadeIn(); }
if(getId == "zz4") {  $("#zz5").fadeIn(); }
});
```

I'm Using dynamic data and number of div will change according data so it will not work is there any better way to show next div with same class... Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery `.next()` method. Here is a link to documentation - https://api.jquery.com/next/

So the code would look like this:

```
$('.box').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).next().fadeIn();
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p8Lvu80f/

EDIT: You should of course add some condition, so `.next()` is not called on last element for obvious reasons, and possibly start over.

Comment: @Joe I've added the fiddle.

Comment: @Joe  look the second answer it's like what you need to do

Comment: @zelitomas  getting `// tell the embed parent frame the height of the content if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){ window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", { height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height, slug: "p8Lvu80f" }], "*") }`  when i clicked last div

Comment: Of course, @Joe will need to add some condition to stop at last div, but it is beyond scope of this question... But I'll update my answer anyway...

Answer (score 1):

I've came up with something. If user clicks the last one, the first child is being shown again.

```js
$('.box').click(function() {
  $(this).index() == $('.box').length ? $('.box').first().fadeIn() : $(this).next().fadeIn();
  $(this).hide();
})
```

```css
.box:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='box' id='zz1'>AA</div>
<div class='box' id='zz2'>BB</div>
<div class='box' id='zz3'>CC</div>
<div class='box' id='zz4'>DD</div>
<div class='box' id='zz5'>EE</div>
```

Comment: this is best solution so far.+1

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.box').click(function(){
 $(this).hide();
 var getId = $(this).attr('id'); 
 var idInt = parseInt(getId)+1;
 var idStr = getId.substring(0, getId.indexOf(idInt))+idInt;
 $("#"+idStr).fadeIn(); 
});
```

This extracts the integer from the clicked ID, adds one, constructs a new ID, and fades in the new ID.

This will work for the data examples you've posted.